# Does postgres know about the storage layout on disk?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have been reading about indexes in postgres and how they are implemented internally. My search took me to B-trees in which the node size is decided based on the block size.

Considering that what PostgreSQL perceives as a single block might translate to multiple blocks on disk due to OS differences, how does this potentially contribute to varying levels of disk reads and overall performance? Are there specific measures or optimizations PostgreSQL employs to mitigate performance discrepancies in such scenarios?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: 4 question marks = 4 questions - your Stack Overflow question should focus on a *specific* question.

Answer (score 2):

The disk block size in PostgreSQL is 8kB. The problem you describe should only be a problem if the block size of the file system is greater than that, so that you'd end up reading unnecessary data. I have never heard of a file system with a block size like that. If reading a single database blocks causes several disk blocks to be read, that shouldn't be a problem. If you are worried about that, set up your file system block size to match the PostgreSQL block size as good as possible.

PostgreSQL has no idea about the underlying hardware, so it doesn't specifically optimize for it. You can set some parameters like `random_page_cost` that you can use to tell PostgreSQL about the characteristics of your storage.

Comment: if the block size on Postgres is greater than the block size of the file system, wouldn't that lead to more IO operations?. Eg, if the file system has a block size of 8kb, then we just do one disk read whereas if the block size of file system is 4kb, for reading the same amount of data we have to do 2 disk reads. Which is expensive. Isn't it then advisable to change the block size of postgres(make it same as the file system) for better performance?

Comment: You can benchmark it and see if you can measure a difference. Won't modern hardware and software merge these I/O requests, so that it makes no difference?